# How do I fix the pinescript v4 error 'line 21: Could not find function of function reference 'nw_regression'.'

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

I'm building a strategy for day trading, and it should be working but I am not sure why this error pops up when I try to use and assign the Nadaraya-Watson Envelope indicator.

This is my code:

```
//@version=4
study("AMD 1m Strategy", overlay = true)

// Define AMD 1m chart
amd = security('AMD', '1m')

// Define ultimate moving average (UMA)
uma = wma(amd, length = 24)

// Define moving average convergence divergence (MACD)
macd = ema(amd, 12) - ema(amd, 26)
signal = sma(macd, 9)

// Define relative strength index (RSI)
rsi = rsi(amd, 14)

// Define quantitative qualitative estimation (QQE MOD)
qqe_mod = sma(rsi, 14)

// Define Nadaraya-Watson envelope
nw_upper = nw_regression(amd, length = 24, k = 1.5)
nw_lower = nw_regression(amd, length = 24, k = -1.5)

// Identify consolidating markets
consolidation = uma > nw_upper and uma < nw_lower

// Identify breakouts
long_breakout = crossover(uma, nw_upper)
short_breakout = crossunder(uma, nw_lower)

// Identify bull and bear markets
bull_market = uma > nw_upper
bear_market = uma < nw_lower

// Comprehensive risk management
risk = 0.01 * 1e-6

// Fibonacci levels
fib_level_1 = 1 - 0.236
fib_level_2 = 1 - 0.382
fib_level_3 = 1 - 0.618

// Enter and exit trades based on fibonacci levels
if (consolidation and long_breakout and macd > signal and rsi > qqe_mod)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop = fib_level_1 * amd)
    strategy.exit("Long Target 1", "Long", limit = fib_level_2 * amd)
    strategy.exit("Long Target 2", "Long", limit = fib_level_3 * amd)

if (consolidation and short_breakout and macd < signal and rsi < qqe_mod)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop = fib_level_1 * amd)
    strategy.exit("Short Target 1", "Short", limit = fib_level_2 * amd)
    strategy.exit("Short Target 2", "Short", limit = fib_level_3 * amd)

// Grid feature for sideways and volatile markets
grid_dist = atr(amd, 14)
grid_num = 5

if (consolidation)
    for i = 1 to grid_num
        strategy.entry("Long Grid " + tostring(i), strategy.long, qty = 100 * risk / grid_dist, limit = uma + i * grid_dist)
        strategy.entry("Short Grid " + tostring(i), strategy.short, qty = 100 * risk / grid_dist, stop = uma - i * grid_dist)

if (bull_market)
    strategy.entry("Long Trend", strategy.long, qty = 100 * risk / grid_dist, limit = uma + grid_dist)

if (bear_market)
    strategy.entry("Short Trend", strategy.short, qty = 100 * risk / grid_dist, stop = uma - grid_dist)

// Stop loss and take profit
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long Trend", stop = fib_level_1 * amd, loss = risk)
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Short Trend", stop = fib_level_1 * amd, loss = risk)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long Trend", limit = fib_level_3 * amd, profit = risk)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Short Trend", limit = fib_level_3 * amd, profit = risk)
```

The exact error messages are as followed:

```
// Define Nadaraya-Watson envelope
nw_upper = nw_regression(amd, length = 24, k = 1.5)
nw_lower = nw_regression(amd, length = 24, k = -1.5)
```

I am trying to use the Nadaraya-Watson Envelope indicator within my strategy, but it does not work while all the other indicators do.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues here.

You cannot use any `strategy.*` functions and variables in a `study`. So, you must change your script's type to a `strategy`.

Your use of the `security()` function is not correct either. The ticker id and timeframe you pass are not valid. Also, you should be passing an expression as a third parameter. See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) for more explanation.

The function `nw_regression()` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am still unsure how to define the nw_regression() function.